# Return Boolean value when table has data in the specified range

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I need a query to return boolean when there's table has data in the given range.

Assume table 
Customer
[User ID, Name, Date, Products_Purchased]

I'm trying to do:

> select case when exists(
>
> select Date, count(*)
>   from Customer
>
> where date between '2015-08-03' and '2015-08-05'
>
> )
>
> then cast(1 as BIT)
>
> else case(0 as BIT)end;

This is throwing an error near "select Date".
However, weird part is the inner query is running perfectly fine.

Im wondering if im missing out something here !

Comment: "The inner query is running perfectly fine": good and well, but it make sense to compute a `count(*)` in the context of an `exists` sub-query?

Comment: Yes, count(*) is not required here.. I used it to check the count of dates.

Comment: I guess you are a SQL Server user, because (1) you want a SELECT without a FROM and (2) you expect a data type named BIT. Sorry, that combination does not work with Hive (nor Oracle, DB2, etc)

Comment: No.. I'm a Java guy.. :D

Answer (score 0):

What about something more straightforward e.g.

```
select case when count(*) >0 then 1 else 0 end as HIT
from ... where ...
```

That way you don't have to bother about Hive assuming that EXISTS implies a correlated sub-query, automagically translated into a MapJoin, i.e. a Java HashMap shuffled to the 2nd line of Mappers jobs, etc. Not exactly your use case.

Then it's not useful to compute the exact count, so the query could be refined as

```
select case when count(*) >0 then 1 else 0 end as HIT
from
 (select ... from ... where ... limit 1) X
```

*[Edit]* There is no "bit" datatype in Hive. But the default "int" should be OK if you just want a return flag (zero / non-zero)

Comment: Thanks for reply and explanation. But im getting error "FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:55 cannot recognize input near 'bit' ')' 'HIT' in primitive type specification [DB Errorcode=11]". Im using Hive on Spark 0.9 cluster.. I should have mentioned this earlier..

Comment: Replace "bit" with "smallint" - there is no such thing as a BIT in Hive. My mistake, I should have actually tested it.